# session timestamp in yii2 is not updating

Tags: session, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using DB table to store session. Whenever I access any page in website, `expire` value in `session` table is getting updated.
I store a value in the session using the following api:

> Yii::$app->session->set("key", $value);

After I use this command, session `expire` is not updating in database.

Another problem is that the stored value in session is only accessible during the same request.
Next request that value is not there in the session.

I google'd and tried all my luck but not able to figure why this is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your controller's code? if possible